# Was Nurph part of the original Pantheon?

Tags: threadbare

In the *Generica Online* series of books, it's established pretty early on that a system is in place over the world, creating an RPG interface for everyone living there. In *Threadbare: Friends With Bunny Feets* we get a description of Nurph, the god of fairness.

> Nurph was the god of honor, fair play, and sportsmanship. He seemed to have some sort of control over fundamental functions of reality and spent most of his time nudging and tweaking various magics and skills with the intent of attaining some sort of “balance” for everyone. It was very much an unending struggle, and his priests had the unenviable job of going out to people whose lives had literally changed overnight when the skills they had depended on for their living changed without warning.

For the reader, it's pretty obvious that they are describing the act of nerfing abilities in a game, but elsewhere in the series, they establish that the world had its own set of deities, and history, prior to the change. So, was Nurph a party of that? An addition? A change of an existing deity?

Comment: The wiki is not very enlightening on the subject; https://generica-online.fandom.com/wiki/Nurph

Comment: Nurph was around before the changeover "*Nurph is… okay with the changeover. At least everyone has no excuse for not knowing the rules, anymore. But sweet HIM, there’s so much work to do. It looks like whatever force was in charge of the changeover left loopholes and expoits EVERYWHERE! He’s gonna be fixing those for the next millenia or two, at LEAST.*"

Comment: @Valorum I can post that tonight, if you haven't gotten around to it.

Comment: It would be far better coming from soneone who's actually read these things. I've no idea what a good answer looks like to this question.

Comment: @Valorum: Can you say which book you found that in? I'm having difficulty finding that quote in my books.

Comment: https://www.royalroad.com/fiction/15130/threadbare/chapter/181881/background-interlude-2-1-on-gods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Valorum's comment, an [Interlude](https://www.royalroad.com/fiction/15130/threadbare/chapter/181881/background-interlude-2-1-on-gods) in the initial Royal Road draft of *Threadbare: Stuff and Nonsense* indicates that the closest that the Changeover did to creating a new god was RNG (who may or may not be a cross-dressing Rando). I will check with the author as to whether this material is still canonical, but until then, I will assume that Nurph was always part of the setting, as per the interlude's text.

> Nurph is... okay with the changeover. At least everyone has no excuse for not knowing the rules, anymore. But sweet HIM, there's so much work to do. It looks like whatever force was in charge of the changeover left loopholes and exploits EVERYWHERE! He's gonna be fixing those for the next millenia or two, at LEAST.

And [confirmed by the author](https://twitter.com/AndrewSeiple/status/1736926360591822938?t=hBBsCzbRIX7GzPSGd3Pm1A&s=19)

[image: My question and the author's answer]

> @AndrewSeiple Just looking for confirmation, is the information the Interlude on the Royal Road copy of Threadbare still correct, that all of the deities (except maybe RNG) predate the Changeover?

> Yeah, that about sums it up.

Comment: Excellent work getting an author confirmation.

Comment: Of course, the sixth *Threadbare* book, *An End to All Tails*, indicates that this will no longer be the case, but that's plot for those who get that far. :-D Really hoping he explains the actual Changeover one of these days.